# LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so for Apache with Django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to run django site with apache mod_wsgi , but as per django documentation whenever i write following in httpd.conf file :

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Apache server fails to start , Issue was that mod_wsgi module was not present in apache24 modules directory and due to it following line was causing issue

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

I am trying to get this mod_wsgi.so file but i could find it anywhere .
I downloaded mod_wsgi-4.4.12.tar.gz from below url but there also i cant get mod_wsgi.so file .

https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi

I tried getting it from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi  but here files are with extension .whl

at one link its written that we can build our own mod_wsgi.so with help of nmake command nmake -f apXYpyXY-winNN-VC?.mk but in windows i get error nmake is not recogiznised as a command .

Please suggest . I am using Windows 7  , Python 2.7 , 64 bit , Apache 2.4 64 bit and Apache 2.2 32 bit .

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
DirectoryIndex  index.py default.py wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath "{$path}\python\Lib;{$path}\python\Lib\site-packages;{$path}\python\DLLs"
WSGIPythonHome "{$path}\python"
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Let `{$path}` be the directory where Python Folder is installed/located. Notice the change in [WSGIPythonPath](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath) and [WSGIPythonHome](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome).

You can search for pre-compiled binaries from here:
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/tree/master/win32#using-the-pre-compiled-binaries

Also mowd_wsgi's [Quick Configuration Guide](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question. But to help anyone facing the same issue, the .so files can be found here: (I spent hours finding it)
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases

Be sure to read the note provided by the developer to know which version is the one you need.
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst

Add: remember to change the version you downloaded to mod_wsgi.so before load it into \wamp\bin\apache[apache2.4.9]\modules